# MVC - throwing exceptions but give message to say I must return a value from List

Tags: c#

This is related to my other post. I am trying to add in some exception logic so I coded the following:

```
public IEnumerable<DrillFormat> List(string partitionKey)
        {
            try {
                _drillServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;  // set when you will not be updating this entity
                var results = from c in
_drillServiceContext.drillTable
                          where c.PartitionKey == partitionKey
                          select c;
                var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
                var queryResults = query.Execute();
                return queryResults;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(e.Message
+ Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception("Error while accessing the data store.", e);
            }

        }
```

but now I get a message saying that "not all code paths return a value". Does that mean I have to return a value even if I throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

If no exception is thrown this method will never return a value.

I usually put a `return null` or `new List<DrillFormat>()` in methods like this.  Depends what the calling code expects and whether you want to handle null up the call chain.